# PHP navigating parent folders

Tags: php

I can not find a good example/explanation on how to traverse directories in a PHP script.

I have to call a class from a directory that is a great-great-great...great-great grandparent of the current file.

Since the directory of the file I cam calling is closer to the root than the current php script, I just want to say "c:\folder\script.php".

when I use `require_once (dirname('c:/folder/').'script.php');` I get config errors.

This is on IIS.  Is the slash direction a factor?

Comment: Can't you do relative paths with `../../../script.php`?

Comment: Yeah, but the relative file is not very close to the required file. It would be a whole lotta dots and slashes.  I'm trying to avoid that.

Comment: Why are you using dirname? what is the exact config error you get?

Comment: You don't need that `dirname()` call in there - also, what config errors are you getting?

Comment: Also you can use `realpath()` with relative paths.

Comment: Run `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and `ini_set('display_errors', true);` at the start of your script.  500 is just the generic "fatal error" code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the slash matters between Windows/Linux. That's why the [DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR](http://www.php.net/manual/en/dir.constants.php) constant was invented, they differ per build. You should be able to:

```
define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR); // Alias to keep it short and readable
require_once('C:' . DS . 'folder' . DS . 'script.php');
```

Comment: Windows has recognized Unix-style directory separators for decades.

Comment: This worked.  Both slash styles did not work before, but this did the trick.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It might be more suitable to transverse from the root directory.

Generally this is represented by a "/"

```
require_once("/some/script.php");
```

Or, define a base directory on the top of executing script and use this as the helper variable on your links. Below is an example:

```
define("BASEDIR", "../../../../"); // Point to the great great great grans parents just once and use them
```

Comment: Putting the `/` at the front of the string signifies the root directory of which directory?

Comment: It points to the server's root directory. The document root of the site.

Comment: so the defined domain of the host (ie, "c:\inetput\wwwroot\mysite"), or the wwwroot (ie, "c:\inetput\wwwroot")?

Comment: AFAIK, domain of the host. But I cannot confirm this, so check it and make necessary adjustments.